# Disable scrolling with stylus on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, stylus-pen

I am trying to cancel scrolling on UIScrollView if it's coming from stylus (Apple Pencil).

Any Advice?

Answer (score 4):

You can set the `allowedTouchTypes` property on a UIGestureRecognizer.

For example:

```
scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes = [UITouchType.direct.rawValue as NSNumber]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find out if touch is from stylus of fingure usinng UITouch's type.

```
if (touch.type == UITouchTypeStylus) {
     //its touch from Stylus.
}
```

Now, for scrollview, You can create Subclass of UIScrollview and implement TouchBegan Method

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if (touch.type == UITouchTypeStylus) {
       self.scrollEnabled = NO;
     }
    else
    {
       self.scrollEnabled = YES;
    }
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if (touch.type == UITouchTypeStylus) {
      self.scrollEnabled = NO;
    }
    else
   {
      self.scrollEnabled = YES;
   }
   [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

}
```

// edit 
OR

Subclass UIApplication :

```
 @interface MyUIApplication : UIApplication
  - (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

        [super sendEvent:event];
        NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
        if ([allTouches count] > 0) {

             / 
             UITouchPhase phase = ((UITouch *)[allTouches anyObject]).phase;
             if (phase == UITouchPhaseBegan){

                   UITouch *touch = [allTouches  anyObject];


                if (touch.type == UITouchTypeStylus) {


                   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"DisableScroll"  object:self];
                 }
               else
                {

                   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"EnableScroll"  object:self];
                 }
             }

        }
    }
    @end




int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
          @autoreleasepool {
                return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, NSStringFromClass([MyUIApplication class]), NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
          }
    }
```

Add observer for these notification in class containing scroll view and enable/Disable scroll accordingly.

Comment: I already tried this, but for some reason touchesBegan is being triggered after the scroll starts so scrollEnabled is being applied in the next time i touch. (The first time i scroll with the stylus the scroll works)

Comment: this function `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` (Exists in UIScrollView delegate) is begin triggered before any thing else (Even before `touchesBegan`). If there is any way to get the type of the touch at this point i think it should work.

Comment: If that's case, you can subclass UIApplication and can use  sendEvent method. Let me add more detail in answer.